# Visual Studio 2022 CANNOT turn off JavaScript Debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

Is there a for-sure way to turn off JavaScript Exception breaking in Visual Studio?

I'm developing a C# module for a third party product, so I can't fix the JavaScript or remove it.

The Debugger will not respect the exception settings.  I have turned off Breaking on all exceptions.  I have gone the the option menu and disabled all JavaScript and Just-in-time  debugging.  Still, every time I debug this page, I break on an unhandled JavaScript exception; which happens every 10 seconds as the thirds party product keeps throwing errors.

Things I have turned off:

1. Debug->Windows->Exception Settings-> (All boxes unchecked)
2. Tools->Options->Debugging->General-> (All boxes unchecked with "Enable" and "JavaScript" like "Enable Java Script debugging"
3. Tools->Options->Debugging->Just-In-Time->(All boxes unchecked)

Answer (score 20):

You can go to `Tools > Options > Debugging > General >` and then in the right part almost like in the middle of the scroll you'll find the option to enable or disable JavaScript debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that resetting all environment settings.

Go to Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Check "Reset All Settings" and next -> Check "No, Just reset.." and next. On this part, I did that to General, JavaScript, Web Development and Web Development (Code Only).

It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the toolbar button that launches the debugger with your selected browser, there is a menu that can be expanded. That menu includes a submenu to enable or disable script debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running multiple project at start up like Angular SPA template then

1. Right click solution
2. Configure Startup Projects
3. Set action to `Run without Debugging`